# "invalid operation" on shader loading and compiling

Tags: opengl, haskell, glut, glfw

### Problem

Having a shader program in `a.vs` as:

```
#version 330
in vec2 vPosition;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and given:

```
import qualified Graphics.GLUtil as GLU
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL
```

this line:

```
vs <- GLU.loadShader GL.VertexShader $ shaderPath </> "a.vs"
```

causes:

> GL: Error InvalidOperation "invalid operation"

at runtime.

### Details

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.10.2. The OpenGL context is set via GLFW with:

```
GLFW.windowHint $ GLFW.WindowHint'OpenGLDebugContext True
GLFW.windowHint $ GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMajor 3
GLFW.windowHint $ GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMinor 3
GLFW.windowHint $ GLFW.WindowHint'OpenGLForwardCompat True
GLFW.windowHint $ GLFW.WindowHint'OpenGLProfile GLFW.OpenGLProfile'Core
```

giving an OpenGL 3.3 context.

The context of the code can be found at this [repository](https://github.com/Jefffrey/Snok/tree/d04afcd5548ea3ea270a34fdab6f6f70359cb920) (link to the specific commit), and specifically in `Main.hs`.

### Question

What can I do to fix this issue or get more debugging informations?

Comment: Please make sure that OpenGL is not in an error state before you do your stuff. Some extension loader wrapper (which are required to obtain the 3.3 functions) are known to leave OpenGL in a error state which must be cleared, so that one doesn't fool himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code under gDebugger, and it made it plain:

```
GL.matrixMode $= GL.Projection
GL.loadIdentity
GL.ortho2D 0 (realToFrac w) (realToFrac h) 0
```

This leftover piece of code was triggering an error state:

> Error-Code: `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`
>
> Error-Description: 
>   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state. The offending function is ignored, having no side effect other than to set the error flag.

As a side note, shader compilation can never trigger an `INVALID_OPERATION` (except when you try to render with a broken pipeline); the compilation errors can be obtained by checking the compilation status directly.